# How to initialize context parameters in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, context-param

I need to set a context param on startup.

```
@Bean
public ServletContextInitializer initializer() {
    return new ServletContextInitializer() {
        @Override
        public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
            servletContext.setInitParameter("joinfaces.primefaces.theme", "poseidon-blue");
        }
    };
}
```

However I get the following error

> Initialization parameters cannot be set after the context has been initialized

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: ServletContext injection always returned null , i can't inject it

Comment: This is an error that occurs when the command is executed , Initialization parameters cannot be set after the context has been initialized